# Learning with noisy labels - how much more data do we need?

Tags: machine-learning, references, supervised-learning

Suppose we have want to perform supervised learning on a dataset with binary labels. The training set is of size N, and we achieve performance (let's say, accuracy) of A% on the test set.

Now, suppose the training set labels are corrupted - C% of labels are flipped. How many more (noisy) samples do we need in our training set to still obtain A% performance on the test set?

Does the required size of the dataset grow linearly with C? Exponentially? Any papers on this?

Comment: If you google "Learning with noisy labels" you can find quite a few papers. See for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567.pdf

Comment: I did, but I did not find anything answering this specific question. How does the required size of the dataset grow with the level of noise in the labels?

Comment: does probability of flipping depends on the class or not? Anyway there's not a singe answer - it depends on the model, and more precisely on the loss function. With a suitable modification of the loss function, you cant still get a good accuracy when 40% of the data are flipped

Comment: @DeltaIV Let's say it doesn't.

Comment: well, then, just set $\rho_{+1}=\rho_{-1}=\rho$ in https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5073-learning-with-noisy-labels.pdf. What do you need more than Lemma 2, Theorem 3 and Theorem 11? TL;DR: by redefining the loss function, you can bound the generalization error by the usual sum of the Rademacher complexity $\mathcal{R}$ times twice the Lipschitz constant $L_{\rho}$ of the new loss function, plus the inverse-square-root of sample size. The only difference is that $L_{\rho}$ is bounded by $\frac{2L}{1-2\rho}$ where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of the original loss function.